# Android: main.xml error

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I'm getting an error when I open my main.xml, I'm not seeing the UI of my app:

```
Eclipse is loading framework information and the layout library from the SDK folder.
main.xml will refresh automatically once the process is finished.
```

Do you have fix on it? I tried googling it but nothing worked for me.

Comment: Post main.xml and the error description with log.

Answer (score 1):

It seems yet another Eclipse quirk. There's a solution here:

http://twigstechtips.blogspot.com/2011/02/eclipse-android-development-is-loading.html

And another alternative here:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/065b4e55f0189873

Answer (score 0):

This is caused when you have old jar files in your sdk directory! look here
http://androidbook.blogspot.com/2009/07/when-eclipse-loading-framework.html

if it doesnt solve the issue maybe you can try changing the target to another version of the SDK eg. 2.2 instead of 2.1 to render the view instead

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me couple days ago after updating SDK through android SDK Manager. When I rebooted eclipse, I got a pop-up saying my Android Development Tool (ADT) or a plugin for Eclipse needs update to version 22.6.2

Here is the information http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

and click updating ADT, the download instructions are in there.

I copied it out here just in case,

Download the ADT Plugin Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software. Click Add, in the top-right corner. In the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter "ADT Plugin" for the Name and the following URL for the Location: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ Note: The Android Developer Tools update site requires a secure connection. Make sure the update site URL you enter starts with HTTPS. Click OK. In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click Next. In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded. Click Next. Read and accept the license agreements, then click Finish. If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the software can't be established, click OK. When the installation completes, restart Eclipse.

It should then work just fine.

Hope this helps.